# Pipe Read fails on Azure

Tags: c#, c++, .net, azure, pinvoke

I have a legacy application that I am trying to run under an Azure worker.  The application uses a fairly common pattern to launch a child process by creating an anonymous pipe, redirecting stdout to the pipe, spawning a child process, then using the pipe to communicate.

To get this to run under Azure, I make a P/Invoke call to the dll that starts this whole process.

All of this works fine outside of Azure, but fails even when running under the emulator.

When running under Azure, the procs are unable to communicate over the pipe.  Specifically, the call to read on the handle to the pipe by the parent is failing (timeout).

Comment: Is your native code compiled for x64?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to step through the code under the emulator and it just blocks on the call to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out that the problem was because the legacy code was duplicating the stdout handle to pass to the child process.

Running under Azure, GetStdHandle for STDOUT was returning 0x0.  This means basically, "No error, but you don't have a STDOUT". Apparently, you need to check for 0x0 AND INVALID_HANDLE.

Creating the handles, setting them on the STARTUPINFO before starting the child instead of duplicating the existing ones fixed everything up.

Answer (score -1):

I have two suggestions as below:

1. May I ask if you are compiling your worker role with .net 4? Using .net 4 has some issue with binding application with network pipes specially when you are P/Invoking, so set your application properties to .net 3.5 profile.
2. Launch this legacy process from startup task with SYSTEM context and setup this application EXE to ProgramEntryPoint in CSDEF so it can be launched directly. Also are you using any IP/Port with this application? Is yes, you would have to write some code in your role onStart() to bind properly.

Let me know what your results are.

Comment: Thanks for -1. Grateful if you please provide some comment on, so that i can understand what was the issue with suggeststion.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect that the reason someone did is because your answer is just made up of questions, which would be more appropriate as comments.

Comment: @Adam, today I worked on your issue with the Azure support engineer and able to get some traction. There are some other ways to resolve this problem and I will add more info later..

Comment: Oh I just saw that you were able to solve this problem. I was able to see in debugger that the handle is 0x0 but had no time to look why and how..Thats great that you could solve it...